# Read from file all lines that have an index `n` lower than the lines that match a given regex

Tags: bash, file, awk, sed

I would like to read from the file `file.txt` all lines that have an index `n` lower than the lines that match a given regex `regex`. For example the file

```
hello my friend
foo
_bar_
I love this bar
poof
kouki
splash in the water
bar
```

if `regex=bar` and `n=2`, then we want to read

```
hello my friend
foo
kouki
```

I found my way through this problem with the cumbersome one liner

```
sed -n `grep -n bar file.txt | awk -F ":" '{print ($1 - 2)}' | tr '\n' 'X'
| sed 's+X+p;+g' | sed 's/.$//'` < file.txt
```

**Is there a better (faster, easier to read) solution?**

(My goal with this question is purely educational)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '/bar/ && FNR>2 {print li[-2]}
       {li[-2]=li[-1]; li[-1]=$0}' file
hello my friend
foo
kouki
```

Which can be made more general to print the **n<sup>th</sup>** line before the match (without having to have the entire file in memory):

```
$ awk -v n=3 '/bar/ && FNR>n{ print li[n]}
              {for (i=n;i>1;i--) 
                    li[i]=li[i-1]
               li[1]=$0}' file
hello my friend
poof
```

Comment: ++ for a solution that performs well, is readable, portable, and generalizes well.

Comment: It is absolutely stunning to me that the slow, fragile, complicated, non-portable, non-extensible sed and bash "solutions" to this are getting upvotes. Of course this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Short ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n '1N;2N;/bar[^\n]*$/P;N;D' file.txt
```

The output:

```
hello my friend
foo
kouki
```

---

*Details*:

- `1N;2N;` - reads the first 3 lines into the pattern space
- `/bar[^\n]*$/` - checks if the last line matches `bar`. (`[^\n]*$` - ensures that it's the last line of the captured 3 lines section)
- `P;` - if the above match is found print the 1st line of the pattern space
- `N` - adds a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space
- `D` - delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space (i.e. regarding the first 3 lines - the 1st line `hello my friend` will be printed and deleted from the pattern space and new cycle will be started at next line `foo`)

Comment: I was searching for this, but you was quicker and powerful! Nice demonstration of use of `P;N;D`!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Wow that looks very elegant +1. I was not familiar with the use of `P`, `N` and `D` in `sed` (I have now read about them in the `man`). Would you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: @Remi.b, sure, give me few minutes

Comment: @Remi.b You could read `info sed` for understanding how this work! ;-)

Comment: While I'm not sure why, this solution doesn't work with BSD/macOS `sed`. I'm resistant to putting in the work to find the reason, however, which brings us to the point, @Remi.b:
It is no accident that you weren't familiar with `P`, `N`, and `D`: these functions are little-known, because they're mind-bending. An `awk` solution such as dawg's is
both much easier to comprehend and to generalize.

Comment: This is `gnu-sed` only it should be stated. POSIX `sed` - nope

Comment: @Remi.b sed is an excellent tool for simple subsitutions on individual lines but that is **all** it should be used for because for anything else an awk solution will be clearer, simpler, more robust, more portable, more efficient, and more easily extensible. If you're using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using constructs that literally became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented so don't waste your time learning them, just learn awk instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
o=0 a=()
while read -r line;do
    a+=("${line}")
    [ "$line" ] && [ -z "${line//*bar*}" ] && echo ${a[o-2]}
    ((o++))
  done <file.txt
hello my friend
foo
kouki
```

Or, because you're speaking about *`regex`*:

```
while read -r line;do
    a+=("${line}")
    [[ ${line}  =~ bar ]] && echo ${a[o-2]}
    ((o++))
  done <file.txt
```

But, for performances, I prefer 1st syntax...

### As a function

```
grepIndex () { 
    local o=0 a=() line
    while read -r line; do
        a+=("${line}")
        [ "$line" ] && [ -z "${line//*$1*}" ] && echo ${a[o-$2]}
        ((o++))
    done
}

grepIndex <file.txt bar 2
hello my friend
foo
kouki
```

Wich could be written

```
grepIndex() {
    local o=0 a=() line
    while read -r line;do
        a+=("${line}")
        [[ ${line} =~ $1 ]] && echo ${a[o-$2]}
        ((o++))
    done
}
```

too.

#### Nota:

If *pure bash* is a lot quicker on small files, for big files, bash become *overkill*!! Have a look at [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488111/1765658)! Using sed could
be one of the most efficient solution for doing this (on big files)!

Comment: I think _underkill_ may be the better term: With anything other than a handful of lines, a pure bash solution will be painfully slow.
If you do only have a handful of lines, the _absolute_ time spent starting up an external utility such as `awk` won't matter, because it's probably still fast enough.
In short: Except for very specific scenarios, _do not read lines in a shell loop_. As an aside: Prefix your `read` commands with `IFS= `, otherwise leading and trailing whitespace will be trimmed.

Comment: Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all, of the reasons not to do this. Just use awk, it's the tool that the guys who invented shell invented to be called from shell for jobs like this.